# Google maps, Change Color of extra Button with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, button

I'm having trouble changing the css of a button (bt) i created in google maps, for each marker on the map i have a button created and i can click both and something happens, but i want the button (bt) to show its active when i click on it by changing its colour. 
Appreciate Any ideas how to do this? 
I'm a hobby noob programmer.

```
var bt = document.createElement('div');
bt.className = 'bigclass';
bt.id = bigid;

var bthtml = '<img src=\"' +big1 + big2 +'\"> <h1>'+big3 + '</h1>' ;
```

This is the click function, that works apart from changing the css. I've tried various ways, the bigid is the unique identifier of each button, but i don't seem to be able to choose it and then change the css (class). i get an error message pretty consistently whatever i try, 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null'

```
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(bt, 'click', function() {
    //document.getElementById(bigid).setAttribute("class", "bigystyle");
    document.getElementById(bt).setAttribute("class", "bigystyle");
    // clicks marker automatically
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');

    var onebigEntry = new createOnebigEntry(bigid, marker, big1, big2, big3);


}); //
```

Comment: The error indicates that you are trying to set an attribute to an element that doesn't exist. Could you please create a demo? From whatever I can see the variable `bt` has an element and not its `id` which could be the reason for failure.

Comment: bt.id = bigid;
i thought i assigned the id here?
If i go alert(bigid) is shows the id, no luck if i go alert(bt.id)

Comment: Yes, you have assigned an id to the element but within the event listener you are trying to access it using the `bt` variable itself which I don't think would work. You should access it with the `id` instead. Also, I am not sure if you are actually adding the `bt` element to the `body` (or some parent) anywhere in your code. As I said earlier, a full demo of your code could be helpful in debugging.

Comment: use `this.setAttribute("class", "bigystyle")`

Comment: Thank you this worked. 

What it does is each button clicked changes color, I was also looking for only the present button being the new color and the other ones revert back to the old color. 

in jquery i do this like this
   ` $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');`

i tried to replicate this using javascript but i can't get it to work though the jQuery does work. can you help translate this to javascript.

i tried these variations
     `document.getElementsByClassName('bigystyle').setAttribute('oldstyle');`
i get error message `setAttribute not a function`!

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a `DOMNodeList`, you must iterate over this list and call `setAttribute` for each item